# App in Android Studio keeps crashing upon clicking submit when trying to share data using Intent and onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener

The app is a general profile app to get familiar with the program since this is my first time using it and I don't have much experience with Java. The main activity has two radio buttons, a radio group, six checkboxes, five textviews (three labels and two to show results) and three edittexts. When you click apply the results from the radio buttons and the checkboxes will show a textview assigned to them. Clicking submit is supposed to move to the next screen that shows the information typed into the EditTexts and selected with the checkboxes and radiobuttons.

**The Main activity java file:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        applyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (cookingbox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedhobby.setText(selectedhobby.getText().toString() + " " + cookingbox.getText().toString());
                }
                if (sportsbox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedhobby.setText(selectedhobby.getText().toString() + " " + sportsbox.getText().toString());
                }
                if (craftbox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedhobby.setText(selectedhobby.getText().toString() + " " + craftbox.getText().toString());
                }
                if (gamebox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedhobby.setText(selectedhobby.getText().toString() + " " + gamebox.getText().toString());
                }
                if (bookbox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedhobby.setText(selectedhobby.getText().toString() + " " + bookbox.getText().toString());
                }
                if (otherbox.isChecked()) {
                    selectedhobby.setText(selectedhobby.getText().toString() + " " + otherbox.getText().toString());
                }
                if (malebutton.isChecked()) {
                    gendertext.setText(malebutton.getText().toString());
                } else if (femalebutton.isChecked()) {
                    gendertext.setText(femalebutton.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent Intent;
                Intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Screen2Activity.class);
                Intent.putExtra("selectedhobby", "");
                Intent.putExtra("editTextText2", "");
                Intent.putExtra("editTextText4", "");
                Intent.putExtra("editTextText3", "");
                Intent.putExtra("gendertext", "");
                startActivity(Intent);
                setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Screen2 Java File:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Screen2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
        ;
        textName = findViewById(R.id.textName);
        textAge = findViewById(R.id.textAge);
        textBirthplace = findViewById(R.id.textBirthplace);
        textHobbies = findViewById(R.id.textHobbies);
        textGender = findViewById(R.id.textGender);

        Intent Intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent != null)
        {
            String editTextText2 = Intent.getStringExtra("editTextText2");
            String editTextText4 = Intent.getStringExtra("editTextText4");
            String selectedhobby = Intent.getStringExtra("selectedhobby");
            String gendertext = Intent.getStringExtra("gendertext");
            Integer editTextText3 = Intent.getIntExtra("editTextText3", -1);
            textName.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Name :  + editTextText2"));
            textAge.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Age :  + editTextText3"));
            textBirthplace.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Birthplace :  + editTextText4"));
            textHobbies.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Hobbies :  + selectedhobby"));
            textGender.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Gender :  + gendertext"));
        }
```

I couldn't get the information from the EditText fields to move to the second activity screen. When I went back into the main activity java file to try to fix the intent errors, I guess I messed up the code for the submit button as well and now neither will work.

Comment: "App in Android Studio keeps crashing" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't include the Logcat code in the body because of length issues, but it says: Name :  + editTextText2
2023-09-17 19:01:24.061  6128-6128  AndroidRuntime          com.example.personalprofile          E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.personalprofile/com.example.personalprofile.Screen2Activity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. You need to give more information. Screenshots or a mockup or something. Why are you appending stuff to the `EditText` fields like that? That is going to be a real mess...

Answer (score 1):

Start by replacing:

```java
            textName.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Name :  + editTextText2"));
            textAge.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Age :  + editTextText3"));
            textBirthplace.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Birthplace :  + editTextText4"));
            textHobbies.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Hobbies :  + selectedhobby"));
            textGender.setText(Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Gender :  + gendertext"));
```

with:

```java
            Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Name :  + editTextText2");
            Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Age :  + editTextText3");
            Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Birthplace :  + editTextText4");
            Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Hobbies :  + selectedhobby");
            Log.d("Screen2Activity", "Gender :  + gendertext");
```

Do not attempt to use the output of `Log.d()`. Just look in Logcat to see what the `Log.d()` call emits in the logging.

Comment: That fixed the submit issue, thank you! How do I get the store information to show up in a TextView? Whenever I try, the only thing that shows up are the phrases used to ID the strings.